# Unable to Install tensorflow-quantum==0.5.1 in VSCode

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, python-3.8, tensorflow-quantum

I'm encountering an issue while trying to install tensorflow-quantum version 0.5.1 in VSCode. I'm using Python 3.8.3. Here's the error message I'm receiving:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-quantum==0.5.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-quantum==0.5.1
```

Despite specifying version 0.5.1 in the installation command, it seems that VSCode is unable to locate a compatible distribution for tensorflow-quantum. I've checked the availability of this version, so I'm unsure why it's not being recognized.

Could you please assist me in understanding why I'm unable to install tensorflow-quantum version 0.5.1 in VSCode? Additionally, if there are any troubleshooting steps or alternative solutions I could try, I'd greatly appreciate your guidance.

Thank you for your help.

I attempted to install tensorflow-quantum version 0.5.1 using the command "pip install tensorflow-quantum==0.5.1" in VSCode. I expected the installation to proceed without errors, as I specified the exact version I wanted. However, I received an error stating that no matching distribution was found for tensorflow-quantum==0.5.1.